# How to classify a document based on the alphanumeric character type order?

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I am using the RAMDirectory in-memory index in lucense.

I want to be able to classify alphanumeric characters by the pattern.

Think of a product SKU that has either letters or numbers.

In my search, the user wants to search for patterns based on if the character is a letter or number.

A = alphabetic character a-z
N = any number

So they would want to search for something like:

```
AANA
```

Which translates too:

letter letter number letter

Example results would be:

```
abc9d

efe4z
```

I am currently just adding documents to my index like:

```
document.add(new StringField("sku", sku, Field.Store.YES)
writer.addDocument(doc)
```

If I wanted to classify each SKU by character type like I described above, how can I do this?  Is it possible with RAMDirectory?

Comment: What `Directory` you are using is irrelevant. Use a [regex query](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Regexp_Searches).

Comment: @femtoRgon is that a very expensive or slow operation in general?  Is there something I can do during index time to speed this up?

Comment: Yes, it will be relatively expensive. I would probably index a field that provides the content in such a way that it is easy to perform this sort of search. Something like what you provided in the question (`AANA`) would make sense to me. That way a simple term query would do the job.

Comment: is it just a typo or am I reading incorrect , search for pattern `letter letter number letter` producing `abc9d` ? I guess `abc9d` would be result for `letter letter letter number letter`.

Comment: probably leading wildcard ;)